# searching for local storage items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have a vue app which can add and edit todos in the local storage, what i am trying to do now is create a search for the item topic which is saved inside of the key value todos in the local storage by using computed in the code in order to filter for the data.

```
<div id="app">

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="text" v-model="search" style=" margin: 20px; padding: 10px;">
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" style="border:2px solid blue; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 15%; position: relative; padding: 10px;">

            <span v-if="todo">  topic:{{todo.topic}}<br> price:{{todo.price}}<br> loc:{{todo.place}}<br> time:{{todo.time_length}} </span>

            <br>
            <br>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>



<script>


    Vue.use(VueLocalStorage);
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                search: '',
                todo: {
                    topic: null,

                },

                todos: null || [],

            }

        },

        watch: {
            todos: function (val) {
                this.$ls.set('todos', val)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.todos = this.$ls.get('todos', this.todos);
            var _this = this;
            this.$ls.on('todos', function (val) {
                _this.todos = val;

            });
        },
        computed: {
            filteredList() {
                return this.todo.filter(todos => {
                    return todos.topic.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                })
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to get the search to work with local storage after searching for a topic.

Comment: What have you tried? What's going on?

Comment: i'm following this link to get the search to work. https://codepen.io/AndrewThian/pen/QdeOVa?fbclid=IwAR0_oNHYtwhS47yGqK_u5VnFqbl6kyha2npZJ__-I9iDlX1lUSoBaW4f8sE

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to call the local storage values as before it was working only with hard coded items